# Why does String.replaceAll(".*", "REPLACEMENT") give unexpected behavior in Java 8?

Tags: java, regex, java-8

Java 8's String.replaceAll(regexStr, replacementStr) doesn't work when the regex given is ".*". The result is double the replacementStr. For example:

```
String regexStr = ".*";
String replacementStr = "REPLACEMENT"
String initialStr = "hello";
String finalStr = initialStr.replaceAll(regexStr, replacementStr);

// Expected Result: finalStr == "REPLACEMENT"
// Actual Result: finalStr == "REPLACEMENTREPLACEMENT"
```

I know replaceAll() doesn't exactly make sense to use when the regex is ".*", but the regex isn't hardcoded and could be other regex strings. Why doesn't this work? Is it a bug in Java 8?

Comment: [`.*` is supposed to match twice](https://regex101.com/r/pgf0Vl/2). That's just how regex works.

Comment: `.*` matches an empty string at the end. Use `.+` instead.

Comment: I want to redact empty strings too.

Comment: If you want to keep nothing of your original string, why use replacement? Just discard your original string completely and use the replacement.

Comment: @khelwood I want to use whatever regex is passed into the function. Sometimes someone wants it all replaced, sometimes not.

Comment: @Hackerman Well, then that someone (if they are knowledgable enough about regex) would not use `.*`, and would use `.+` instead.

Comment: @Sweeper makes sense. I didn't realize that's what regex does with .*

Comment: Just use `replaceFirst` instead of `replaceAll`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// specify start and end of line

String regexStr = "^.*$";
String replacementStr = "REPLACEMENT"
String initialStr = "hello";
String finalStr = initialStr.replaceAll(regexStr, replacementStr);
```

Comment: Both matches of the original pattern are at the end of line, so the `$` does not add anything. Only the start-of-line marker `^` is relevant.